# Does computational complexity theory take into account problems with subjectivity in the verification of a solution?

Tags: complexity-theory, p-vs-np

When we discuss **P vs NP** we are looking at the difference between problems that are **easily solved** versus **easily verified** (wrt polynomial vs exponential time).

But in both cases these are **black-and-white results**. We do/don't solve the problem, we do/don't verify the problem.

What about cases where there is **subjectivity to the verification**? Problems where 2 people don't agree on the solution, since the solution may depend on context, environment, etc.

Does computational complexity deal with the subjectivity in verification, or are all problems modeled as black-and-white results?

Comment: No, subjective problems are not considered; everything is precise here.

Comment: Not quite. NP-hard problems do not have to be decision problems.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Computational complexity doesn't deal with subjectivity.  In computational complexity, we consider [formal languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) that are precisely defined, so there is no subjectivity.

Comment: Ironically, some formal languages are called **context-sensitive**, even though the solution ain't depend on context.

Comment: Keep in mind, NP-hard problems do not have to be decision problems.

Comment: @Cybernetic That doesn't mean they're subjective. *Nothing* here is subjective.

Comment: I don't agree. For example, NP, NP-Complete and NP-Hard are not resolved to yes/no answers. They 100% require the use of approximations, meaning their solutions are imprecise. There is no such thing as an exact solution to an NP problem (ever found). You cannot say everything here is precise.